# VBA Macro to verify if a new file was created or added to a folder

Tags: vba, file, excel

I am not sure if this question was already asked here. I've searched a lot(!) and didn't find the answer.

I wanted to create a macro in VBA to check in a specific folder everyday if there are any new files added.

I have seen some codes to check if the file exists (given a name), but I'm really struggling to find an answer for my question.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Loop through the files in that folder and check for their creation date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the **FileSystemObject**

```
Sub LookForNew()
    Dim n As String, msg As String, d As Date
    msg = ""
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fils = fso.GetFolder("C:\TestFolder").Files
    For Each fil In fils
        n = fil.Name
        d = fil.DateCreated
        If d >= Date - 1 Then
            msg = msg & n & vbTab & d & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next fil
    If msg = "" Then
        MsgBox "No new files"
    Else
        MsgBox msg
    End If
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```